# SQL Server Management Studio Clear Cache Code Completion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

If you change a table, then code completion doesn't work anymore when writing a query in SQL Server Management Studio. Is there a way to clear this cache?

(SQL Server 2008)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can try

> Edit -> Intellisense -> Refresh Local
>   Cache (CTRL+Shift+R)

From [SQL Server 2008 Intellisense update/refresh on schema changes](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/1b17d604-ed60-4a5e-bceb-d67b0e6d7d71)

Comment: I can never remember this one and always have to check back here for this :) I wish SSMS would just periodically do this for us!